# How to Hide files and folder for Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, hidden-files

In Ubuntu I can protect files by hiding them or change the owner and permission. But I am using dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu), so Ubuntu's hidden files and directories are easily visible from Windows.

How can I prevent people from viewing my hidden files in Windows, or how can I make a file hidden for Windows in Ubuntu?

Comment: What kind of file-system are you using? ext3/4? Windows can't read those. Meaning your entire `U:\(Ubuntu)` drive will not me visible!

Comment: @blade19899 Partition is ntfs. Which is visible by ubuntu and windows both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows a file is set to hidden by setting [attributes](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/fileattr.htm), so you can change attributes via [Wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/wine1.3/) command line or [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)

```
wine cmd
attrib +h filename
```

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 2):

To hide files and/or folders in Ubuntu you have two ways:

1. add a '.' (without quotes, obviously) at the beginning of
   file's/folder's name
2. List item if you don't want to rename the file/folder do this: in the same folder as the one in which are saved the files/folders you want to
   hide, create a new text file, and edit it writing the names of the
   files/folders you want to hide. Then save it and rename it as
   ".hidden" (without " too)

To see hidden files press CTRL+H.

Comment: I think he mean to say that the hidden file in ubuntu must be hidden  windows too

Comment: Thanks for the hidden file method, I was trying to do the opposite of what the OP asked for. To hide Windows System files so that I don't accidentally edit them in Linux. This helped as renaming was not an option.

Answer (score -1):

See if you want to hide your files/folder in ubuntu

1.First open the directory containing your files.

2.Make an empty text document named ".hidden"

3.Open this document and then write the name of first file you want to hide go to next line and write second file/folder's name.

4.When you are finished doing description then save the document and after that press "ctrl+h".

5.Your files should be hidden now.

6.Thanx for reading this.

Answer (score -1):

Use some kind of encryption, that's the only way to 100% secure your files, on any filesystem.

If someone has physical access to your computer, nothing prevents them from taking out the hard disk(s), plugging them into another computer, and reading everything from there.

Even without messing with the hardware, i wouldn't trust microsoft's ridiculous idea of "security" any day of the week. Even with everything set to the most paranoid settings, someone might easily be able to write and install a windows driver/exploit to read your linux partitions.